# Catch Python script output in PHP and avoid double output

Tags: php, python

I am executing a Python script in PHP using `system()`. For me to get the result of my Python script, I use `print` command and catch the result in PHP. Here's my code:

**Python (test.py)**

```
import sys
name = sys.argv[1]
print 'Your name is ' + name
```

**PHP**

```
$result = system('python test.py John');
echo $result;

/* PHP Output */
Your name is John
Your name is John
```

As you can see, the output is doubled. The first one was generated by the Python script itself, the second one was because of `echo` command. Is there a way on how to avoid this doubled output? I just wanted to catch the result and will use it somewhere on my PHP script.

**NOTE: Just wondering if there is another way on how to pass Python script output to PHP a variable. My only intention here is to put the output on a PHP variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765473/error-on-using-exec-to-call-python-script

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php) function. It also performs a command execution but, at diference fo *system*, doesn't output the content to standard output. The only drawback is that the return is an array of every line in the stadard output (not a string, like *system*. You can also try with [proc_open](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.proc-open.php), that allows you redirect the output to an arbitrary pipe.